# Need a way to ensure user enters the correct amount, as well as ensuring the user doesn't enter a string

Tags: java, exception

The code here worked until I needed to ensure the user didn't cause an exception by entering a string instead of an integer or double. I basically need to make sure the user enters enough to be greater than or equal to the price, so that the program can return the correct amount of change.

```
public static double findChange()
{
    System.out.println("\nPlease insert: " + price + " (enter payment amount)");

        while (payment < price)
        {
            try {
                payment = kb.nextDouble();
                //takes input until user has entered the needed amount

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter valid currency");
            }
            price = price - payment;
            price = (price * 100) / 100;
            System.out.println("Please insert:" + price);
            if (payment <= price)
                stringError = false;
        }
    } 

    change = payment - price;
    change = Math.round(change * 100);
    change = change / 100;
    System.out.println("\nChange Given: $" + change);
    //determines amount of change to give user and formats to cents

    return change;

}
```

Comment: Don't catch `Exception`: catch a more specific exception type.

Comment: @brso05 Not quite. `Exception` (even precise ones) shouldn't be part of standard control flow logic, they should be used to handle exceptional cases. Scanner introduced `hasNext...` kind of methods precisely to avoid using exceptions.

Comment: @brso05 Creating exception is expensive operation so if there are other ways to prevent them we should use them. `Scanner#hasNext...` is canonical example of such situation.

Comment: @brso05 OK, TIL that `Scanner#hasNextDouble` internally is using try-catch to test type of data which means that there will be no performance gain here so this method is no longer good example of what I try to say (damn you Scanner, but I still hope it will be improved someday). But rule says the same: if we can avoid creating exception (which is expensive operation) we should do so and use other less expensive (and probably more readable) code.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Error: Please enter valid currency");
}
```

to

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Error: Please enter valid currency");
    continue;
}
```

This way, if the user inputs a non `double` value, the error message will be shown and he will be asked to re-enter a value (The `continue;` instruction skips the current iteration & passes on to the next one).

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                payment = kb.nextDouble();
                //takes input until user has entered the needed amount

            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Please enter valid currency");
            }
            price = price - payment;
```

When an exception occurs, this will cause troubles, since payment has no value (or not the right one).

put your  catch statement later in the while block

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            findChanges();
        }

        private static double findChanges()
        {
            string xPrice;
            string xPayment;
            double price = 0d;
            double payment = 0d;
            double change = 0d;
            Console.WriteLine("Please insert price and payment amout");
            Console.WriteLine("Price ?");
            xPrice = Console.ReadLine();
            bool PriceIsNumber = double.TryParse(xPrice, out price);
            Console.WriteLine("Payment ?");
            xPayment = Console.ReadLine();
            bool PaymentIsNumber = double.TryParse(xPayment, out payment);

            if (PriceIsNumber == true && PaymentIsNumber == true)
            {
                if (payment > price)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // price = price - payment;
                        // price = (price * 100) / 100;
                        change = payment - price;
                        // change = Math.Round(change * 100);
                        // change = change / 100;
                        Console.WriteLine("Change = " + change.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // supress or process e
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid currency");
            }
            Console.Read();
            return change;
        }
    }
}
```